# AngularJS: Hide button after click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

New to Angular and struggling with how to do things the "Angular Way". All I want to do is click a button to show a hidden element inside a view then hide the button that was clicked. Any help would be awesome.

HTML:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="showDiv=true; hideMe()">
  Show Div
</button>
<div ng-show="showDiv">
  I was hidden now you see me, but how do I hide the button?
</div>
```

Controller:

```
  $scope.hideMe = function(){
    console.log('hide the button');
    $scope.hide();
  }
```

Code sample: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9FewzdQPFvXiqM2PGfEm?p=preview)

Ideally would like to incorporate

```
ng-hide
```

on the button and not have a function run inside of the controller.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<button ng-hide="showDiv"...
```

Should work also

Answer (score 6):

Just add `ng-show="!showDiv"` to your button, this will hide it if showDiv = true

Just to be clear new html should look:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="showDiv=true" ng-show="!showDiv">Show Div</button>
```